# Hartshorne Ⅱ prop 6.6, irreducible

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to understand the following proposition, which is Hartshorne Ⅱ prop 6.6.

Let $X$ be a noetherian integral separated scheme which is regular in codimension one, then $X \times_{\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}} \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}[t]$ is also a noetherian integral separated scheme which is regular in codimension one and $\operatorname{Cl} X\cong \operatorname{Cl}(X\times_{\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}}\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}[t])$.

I showed when $X$ is affine.
I'm in trouble in general case.

Let $Y$ be a prime divisor of
$X$, then $\pi^{-1}(Y)$ should be a prime divisor of $X\times_{\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}}\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}[t]$.
But I can't show that $\pi^{-1}(Y)$ is irreducible.
$\pi$ is a projetion $X \times_{\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}} \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}[t] \rightarrow X$.
I know $X \times_{\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}} \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}[t]$ is irreducible, so this can be used.

Comment: $\pi^{-1}(Y)=Y\times \operatorname{Spec} \Bbb Z[t]$...

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Why $\pi^{-1}(Y)=Y\times \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}[t]$ ?
I know  that this is true in a category of sets, but in a category of schemes, I don't know.
I'm glad if you tell me an explanation or a good reference.
Sorry for the rudimentary question.

Comment: If you understand why this is true in the affine case, you should understand it in the general case via covering $X$ with affine opens. If you require more assistance, please edit your post to clarify where specifically you're stuck and how far you can get.